# Developing for Linux, MAC & Windows Desktop

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin

I find a lot of information on developing cross-platform for mobile platforms, but not for the desktop.

Using C#, I want to create three flavours of a DESKTOP based application. All will share the core application shared code, but the Ui I want to make more platform specific, as well as the packaging...

- .deb for Linux
- .dmg for Mac
- .exe for Win

The latter one isn't a problem ofcourse, but I can't find anything on compiling to .app or .deb on Xamarin/Mono resources. Has anyone some ideas?

Comment: Better fit for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If cross platform is a requirement, I probably wouldn't be looking at C#...

Comment: @yv Aside from the relative off-topicness of this question, please note that signatures, thanks and other similar text is considered noise on Stackoverflow and should not be included in questions or answers.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit then, where should I be looking? C# is the language I'm the most comfortable with and most of the assets of our company are in C#.. that's why

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit Mono supports winforms, and GTK+ which are desktop UI technologies, and it runs on all the mentioned platforms. Elaborate??

Comment: ps, @Austin, fyi, "softwarerecs" didn't like the topic: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/developing-for-desktop-platforms-of-linux-mac-windows

Comment: @YvesSchelpe Apologies,I thought you were looking for a tool that would package up the application for cross platforms; which would be on topic per this meta http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/9/43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin is an umbrella for mobile and OS X solutions so far. Not sure if they plan to expand to Linux and Windows. But the core idea is highly extensible, share the core libraries and build individual UI ones for each OS.

Packaging is a process after you compile the binaries. As the platforms are different, the packaging processes are also different,

`.deb` is its own standard, which is generally documented by Ubuntu/Debian communities, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/what-is-the-simplest-debian-packaging-guide

`.dmg` is for Mac, and Xamarin.Mac provides streamlined toolchain. MonoMac once provided such support, but not sure if the old toolchain supports latest OS X releases.

`.exe` is probably a bad idea to go. Do you mean `.msi`? There are tons of tools available in MSI field, from open source tools like [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) to commercial ones such as [InstallAware](http://www.installaware.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I will also try to get in touch with a Xamarin community representative to see what options there are. If I have more, i'll post it here.